# CDATA Issue Within Magento Rotator

Tags: javascript, magento, cdata, static-block

So I'm currently developing a Magento Website. I set up a rotator using the code found here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/cms_and_home_page/javascript_banner_rotator_for_home_page

If I put the code into the homepage it works as it's supposed to. However if I put the code within a static block CDATA forces itself into the code, breaking it. I'm unable to remove the CDATA as it keeps replacing itself. Code Below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var imgs1 = new Array("{{media url="wysiwyg/rotator-1-1.jpg"}}","{{media url="wysiwyg/rotator-1-2.jpg"}}","{{media url="wysiwyg/rotator-1-3.jpg"}}");
var lnks1 = new Array("http://www.example.com/","http://www.example.com/","http://www.example.com/");
var alt1 = new Array("That Looks Nice","That Looks Nice","That Looks Nice");
var currentAd1 = 0;
var imgCt1 = 3;
function cycle1() {
  if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
    currentAd1 = 0;
  }
var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
  banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
  banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
  document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
  currentAd1++;
}
  window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);
// ]]></script>
<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top"> <img id="adBanner1" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/rotator-1-1.jpg"}}" alt="" width="235" height="250" border="0" /></a></p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are commenting the javascript ending `</script>` tag, try putting `</script>` after the line CDATA ends.
Not sure about this, but worth a try.

Comment: If I do that it just edits itself back. Is there a way I can disable whatever is changing the code?

Comment: remove the CDATA code, clear the cache and check if everything is working.

Comment: Did that ages ago, Magneto being as it is.

Also, in case it's worth mentioning the cache is disabled on the site, as it's currently in development.